# Is the Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK intent broadcasted on a Lollipop Android device while the device is sleeping?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, sleep

I'm building an Android app that requires me to send messages to another device via Bluetooth every minute while the phone is sleeping.

This requires me to register a receiver that listens for the Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK intent when the app calls onStop() and unregister it when the app calls either onRestart() or onDestroy().

This worked when my phone was on Android Kitkat, but now that I've updated the OS to Lollipop, Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK does not seem to be broadcasted every minute anymore. In other words, Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK is not consistently issued by the system while the phone is sleeping during Android Lollipop (even though it did work for Kitkat). Therefore, my broadcast receiver listening for this intent is triggered at weird times (sometimes never triggered, sometimes triggered in the middle of a minute).

Is this purposeful or is this an Android bug in the Lollipop OS? Is this in any way related to the fact that the AlarmManager API also does not have exact time deliveries from API 19 now due to the new batch policy that minimizes battery use by "batching" alarms together (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)?

**Most importantly, is there any way around this so that I can still receive updates when the time has changed? Note: I do not want to use the AlarmManager API.**

Thanks in advance!! All help is appreciated.

Comment: How did you solve it at the end?